# Long Running Maps Tasks On An Small HDFS File

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Imagine a scenario you have a text file with say 10000 rows in it and so it will be very small when you save it in the HDFS. Now your goal is to run a map/reduce job on this small file expecting every line of the text file being passed to the mapper. However the processing time for each map k,v is long and you want to launch as many as mappers on the cluster to get the maximum possible parallelism to finish the mapping job the soonest.

Because the file is small, it could be save in one or two hdfs blocks only and I assume the number of provisioned maps by hadoop for the job is going to be equal to the number of hdfs blocks which happened to be one or two. But this is undesired as you want to launch as many as possible mappers. Here are my questions?

1. What are my options on controlling the proper number of mappers for my scenrio of processing on an small file?
2. What are the pros and cons of each available options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approach is to use the [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html). According to the documentation `NLineInputFormat which splits N lines of input as one split`. The con of this approach is that data locality is lost, since the data is small it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I used the text file as an example so if the input file is not a text file, I have to write my own InputFormat? At what step the inputformat is being called? How many instance of it are running on the system? Do we have run an instance of the input format for each hdfs block?

Comment: The splits are calculated on the client. Check the [NLineInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.22.0/mapreduce/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.java) code, this is where the splits are calculated and a RecordReader is also returned. If the other InputFormats don't provide this sort of functionality, then you might have to write your own InputFormat class.